# Merge two objects in Python

Tags: python, object, dictionary, merge, built-in

Is there a good way to merge two objects in Python? Like a built-in method or fundamental library call?

Right now I have this, but it seems like something that shouldn't have to be done manually:

```
def add_obj(obj, add_obj):

    for property in add_obj:
        obj[property] = add_obj[property]
```

Note: By "object", I mean a "dictionary": `obj = {}`

Comment: all objects do not have the [] accessor. Are you refering to dictionnaries?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two Python dictionaries in a single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-python-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression)

Comment: The title is misleading. It should be: *Merge two dictionaries in Python*.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

If `obj` is a dictionary, use its [`update`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) function:

```
obj.update(add_obj)
```

Comment: be very careful, as you are updating `obj` in-place; I would rather go with @Anony-Mousse answer

Answer (score 40):

How about

```
merged = dict()
merged.update(obj)
merged.update(add_obj)
```

Note that this is really meant for dictionaries.

If `obj` already is a dictionary, you can use `obj.update(add_obj)`, obviously.

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> A = {'a': 1}
>>> B = {'b': 2}
>>> A.update(B)
>>> A
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

on matching keys:

```
>>> C = {'a': -1}
>>> A.update(C)
>>> A
{'a': -1, 'b': 2}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
new_obj = {
 **obj,
 **add_obj,
}
```